# Open-source driver for AMD Radeon HD 6490M

Tags: drivers, ati, graphics, radeon, open-source

I have HP ProBook 4530s laptop with AMD Radeon HD 6490M graphics card. After installing Ubuntu it runs on Intel Sandybridge graphics.
[The Ubuntu community page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/ATI#Introduction) says: "By default Ubuntu will use the open source ATI or Radeon driver for cards manufactured by AMD/ATI."
I already have installed the required driver packages: `xserver-xorg-video-ati xserver-xorg-video-radeon xserver-xorg-video-vesa xserver-xorg-video-intel xserver-xorg-video-all`, but it uses Intel driver anyway.
When I'm uninstalling the Intel driver (`xserver-xorg-video-intel`) and rebooting, Radeon graphics works, it uses Gallium driver, but only 2D session loads.
[This page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RadeonDriver#Recommended_configuration_for_X.org) says: "No configuration is necessary for ATI driver in the modern versions of Ubuntu." and I'm using Ubuntu 12.04.
What's wrong?
P.S. I don't want the proprietary FGLRX driver, it's really buggy on my system.

Comment: Do you by chance have hybrid graphics?

Comment: Yes, I have hybrid graphics.

Comment: Can you disable the Intel GPU from the BIOS?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried this?

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge xorg-driver-fglrx fglrx*  
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libgl1-mesa-glx libgl1-mesa-dri fglrx-modaliases  
sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg

sudo apt-get install --reinstall xserver-xorg-core
```

This should make your system use the opensource driver. It worked for me. I have a different computer but it has a Radeon HD 4000 series

Comment: Nah! It runs on Intel GPU :( People are having a lot of problems caused by their AMD graphics card.

Answer (score 0):

Definetily the issue that I faced.  I wrote this article as a solution that worked for me.

[ATI Radeon HD 6750 Ubuntu 13.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/370240/ati-radeon-hd-6750-ubuntu-13-10/389112#389112)

Comment: You are much appreciated for trying to help a person. But you must give context for links ie explain whatever is in the link you are providing. See here :- http://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-answer under "Provide context for links" heading. This is not intended to offend you but just to make your answer better and useful for the community.